# Removing TODO lines from C files

Tags: shell, sed, replace, scripting, grep

I have several .c and .h files which contain TODO and Fixme messages internally.
I want to remove them using a shell script.
The problem is TODO or Fixme messages can be in a single line or in the same line with code.

```
// TODO : single line todo
// Fixme : single line fixme
if(test != 0) // Fixme : code line fixme
```

I could write a shell command using find & sed to remove a single line TODO message as follows;

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec sed -i '/TODO/d' {} \;
```

I need a trick to remove the code line fixme too.

Thanks

Comment: `sed -i 's#\(.*\)//.*\(TODO\|Fixme\).*#\1#'`

Comment: @SamuelKirschner thank you, that was helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only delete lines starting with // use `^`.

```
sed '/^\/\/.*TODO/d'
```

than to replace the lines that have both comment an no comment use `s` instead of `d`

```
sed 's#//.*TODO.*##'
```

combine these with find in one sed command

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec sed -i '/^\/\/.*TODO/d;s#//.*TODO.*##' {} \;
```

now you can take care of spaces and the Fixme as well in the same sed, but it gets a little long:

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec sed -i '/^ *\/\/.*\(TODO\|Fixme\)/d;s# *//.*\(TODO\|Fixme\).*##' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd just use awk for simplicity:

```
$ awk 'sub("// (TODO|Fixme) .*","") && !NF{next} 1' file
if(test != 0)
```

The above just says "remove text starting with '//' then 'TODO' or 'Fixme' and if the resulting line is empty then delete it" which I think is exactly what you want. No complications, no duplicate conditions, and it'll work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Just like GNU sed supports "inplace" editing with `-i`, so does GNU awk with `-i inplace` so you can use that in your find command if you like:

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec awk -i inplace 'sub("// (TODO|Fixme) .*","") && !NF{next} 1' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` to do the job:

```
sed -Ei '/^$/n;s/(^|\;)[/]{2}[ ]*(TODO|Fixme).*$/\1/;/^$/d' file
```

You could integrate the files using the `exec..+` and run `sed` in one take

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec sed -Ei '/^$/n;s/(^|\;)[/]{2}[ ]*(TODO|Fixme).*$/\1/;/^$/d' {} +
```

---

<sup>**Tip:** The `-E` option with `sed` enables extended regular expression engine. If it is not supported, use `-r`.</sup>